# Azure Functions - Could not load file or assembly ''AzureFunctions.Autofac.Shared'

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-functions

I have Azure Functions project and I am using Autofac dll for DI in Azure functions. While trying to run the function using VS 2017 (community), it throws an exception -

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'AzureFunctions.Autofac.Shared, Version=3.0.6.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Things that I have tried to resolve the issue -

1. Uninstall "AzureFunctions.Autofac" NuGet packet and reinstalled it.
2. Restarted VS even my machine
3. Made sure I have Azure storage emulator and Azure CLI installed.
4. Checked all "AzureFunctions.Autofac" NuGet packages are loaded correctly in project.
5. Tried to Google it but couldn't find a concrete solution.

What could be wrong here and how to debug this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try downgrading the version of "AzureFunctions.Autofac" to 3.0.5. Make sure you don't have multiple version of same assembly in your project.

Comment: I am already using version 3.0.6 version and using .Net Core 2.2. And I am still facing the same issue. I also have single version of the assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure this is not checked.

[image: Make sure this is not checked.]

Answer (score 2):

I tried with version 3.0.6 as well and it worked. Below are some screenshots from my solution for the reference :

[image]
[image]

```cs
public class DIConfig
    {
        public DIConfig(string functionName)
        {
            DependencyInjection.Initialize(builder =>
            {
                builder.RegisterType<NaiveInvestementAllocator>().As<IInvestementAllocator>(); // Naive

            }, functionName);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Also make sure you have all the required dependency mentioned in the [Nuget Document](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureFunctions.Autofac)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I am already using version 3.0.6 version and using .Net Core 2.2.
And I am still facing the same issue. Do you have any further idea about this?

Comment: @AparnaGadgil Check my answer above, that might help.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue.  My Visual Studio exception settings were modified (some earlier issue I was attempting to resolve).

The exception settings needed to be RESET. It seems that the file not found it being thrown regardless, and the emulator will not run once the exception has been captured by the IDE.